# Theorem statement in the title frame of an mdframed environment?

Tags: theorems, mdframed

I've defined a theorem environment using the package `mdframed`. However, I'd like the statement to be contained within a different box from the one which contains the proof.

Ideally, this would be the title frame. However, if I try to put more than one line of text inside it, the text just goes on horizontally, ignoring even `\\`.

I've searched for examples both in the documentation of the package and online and I haven't found any that match what I want. Anyone knows if something like this can be done?

I provide here a minimal working example of my current environment:

[image: Image of the result]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%         Definition of the theorem environment         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{theo}[chapter]\setcounter{theo}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theo}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{teorema}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{theo}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\thetheo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=Violet!20,draw= Violet!50, double= Violet!50]
{\strut Teorema~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=Violet!20,draw= Violet!50, double=Violet!50]
{\strut Teorema~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=Violet!50,backgroundcolor=Violet!5,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true, 
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,roundcorner=10pt}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\vspace{-0.25cm}}{\qed\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\begin{teorema}[The theorem's statement]
Its proof
\end{teorema}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `\stepcounter{theo}\protected@edef....` instead of using `\refstepcounter{theo}` ?

Comment: Also, are you sticking to `mdframed`?

Comment: Whoops, yes, there's a reason: ignorance! Thank you very much! As for wether I'm sticking with `mdframed`, not necessarily, I'm open to suggestions. @ChristianHupfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tcolorbox` most of the requests can be done out of the box. Most important is `minipage boxed title=0.8\linewidth`, for example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%         Definition of the theorem environment         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{theo}[chapter]\setcounter{theo}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theo}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{teorema}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{theo}%
%\stepcounter{theo}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\thetheo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=Violet!20,draw= Violet!50, double= Violet!50]
{\strut Teorema~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=Violet!20,draw= Violet!50, double=Violet!50]
{\strut Teorema~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=Violet!50,backgroundcolor=Violet!5,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true, 
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,roundcorner=10pt}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\vspace{-0.25cm}}{\qed\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter]{teoremaother}{Teorema}{%
  boxrule=2pt,
  enhanced,
  colback=Violet!5,
  colframe=Violet!50,
  colbacktitle=Violet!20,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle={\bfseries},
  minipage boxed title=0.8\linewidth,
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=10pt,yshift*={-\tcboxedtitleheight/2}},
  boxed title style={parbox,boxrule=2pt},
  after upper={\qed},
}{th}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\begin{teorema}[The theorem's statement which is a very long, long, long, long text]
Its proof
\end{teorema}

\begin{teoremaother}{The theorem's statement which is a very long, long, long, long text}{}
Its proof
\end{teoremaother}

\begin{teoremaother}{\blindtext}{}
Its proof
\end{teoremaother}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's perfect! Thanks a lot! I didn't know `tcolorbox` was so powerful. I'll definitely switch to using it.

Comment: @HerculePoirot: `tcolorbox` is a swiss knife package ;-)

Comment: @HerculePoirot: One side note: the theorems made by `tcolorbox` have a 2nd mandatory argument meant for the label. Leave it empty if you don't need a label

Comment: Perfect, I'll surely need that label argument. One last question, is there a way to prevent the indentation in every line after the first? Not sure if it's aesthetically a good choice, but just out of curiosity.

Comment: @HerculePoirot: I have to investigate.

Comment: Wow, I'm just browsing the documentation and this package is much more complete and looks much more intuitive than `mdframed`. It even has a native way of dividing boxes in two sections! That would be probably more adequate for my purpose (theorem/proof) than what I'm doing right now. Thanks again!

Comment: @HerculePoirot: Yes, the division was something I wanted to propose you as well rather than the `title` statement